# How to re-run a build with the same parameters scheduled by cron

Tags: jenkins, cron, dsl, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, rebuild

I know about the rebuild and replay functionality, but both of them are manually triggers. So here is our problem:

We have multiple servers which can be deployed with any branch that exists. But this deploy is manually. But we want to ensure, that at least once a day, the latest version of that branch is deployed to avoid having servers being outdated.

So what I want to do it, create a scheduler job that runs once a day and triggers a Jenkins job to rebuild the last job using the exact same parameters.

Would be great if someone has some input here :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the [Persistent Parameter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/persistent-parameter/) and use it to define the relevant parameters inside the deploy job that you want to reuse.
This plugin enables you to set you input parameters (string, text, boolean and choice) with default values taken from the previous build - so every time you run the build with parameters manually or trigger it from another job the values that will be used are the values from the last execution.

Your caller job can still pass parameters to the deploy job during the daily execution - but for all parameters that are not passed their latest value will be used.
You can also override parameters defined as persistent as it just affects the default value.

Comment: A, good idea, will have a look if that works for my use case! But sounds like a good idea